# Lighttpd Zend Framework rewrite bug

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I've set up a certain .htaccess for my specific zend framework (Social Engine) but now need some assistance making this work on a lighttpd server.

basically what happens are 2 things:

1. Zend (for some reason) adds index.php to some url's, so domain.com/users become domain.com/index.php/users
2. The rewrite writes this from `http://domain.com/index.php/test/` to `http://test/`

Keep in mind that http://domain.com/users DOES work.

Here is my Lighttpd.conf setup..

```
#TODO : Fix this line "/(\?(.*))?$" => "/index.php?rewrite=1&$2", - >
#       redirects http://www.domain.com/index.php/test to http:///test/
    ############# Standard Domain
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)domain\.com$" {
        server.document-root = "/home/lighttpd/www.domain.com"
        server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/www.domain.com/error.log"
        accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/www.domain.com/access.log"
        #server.error-handler-404 = "/e404.php"
        url.rewrite-once = (
           "(^/index\.php/admin.*)" => "$1",
           "^/(admin/.*)" => "/index.php/$1",
           "(^/install.*)" => "$1",
           "^/index\.php(\?(.*))?" => "/index.php?rewrite=2&$2",
           #"/(\?(.*))?$" => "/index.php?rewrite=1&$2",
        )
        url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
           "/?(\?(.*))?$" => "/index.php?rewrite=1&$2",
           ".*" => "/index.php?rewrite=1",
        )
    }
```

Comment: Please do not tag questions with Apache-related tags if the question itself is (a) not about Apache-related things and (b) doesn't require any knowledge of Apache to solve.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I didn't mean to cause confusion.